# Sort by shared variable

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports

My report group displays the net cost of the top 10 clients. `{@NetCost}` is a shared variable for calculate sales cost - all taxes and all discounts:

```
if travelType="OW" then
  salesCost-Tax1-Tax2-Tax3-Discount1-Discount2
else 
  (salesCost-Tax1-Tax2-Tax3-Discount1-Discount2)/2

shared currencyvar netCostTotal:=netCostTotal+{@netCost};
```

I know how to sort by one database field, but how can I sort by a running shared variable?

```
   client#   client name     Net Cost
1  1234      XXXXX           150.22
2  2345      XXXXX           140.11
3  4567      XXXXX           120.00
```

Comment: Shared variables are a little iffy, so there's no way to tell if this will work or not, but... Have you tried making a new Formula field that's just your shared variable, then sorting on that Formula field? (Might need to use `whileprintingrecords;` to get it to behave.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to use whileprintingrecords, but it has error on {@netCost}. Only work on shared variable. Can you explain more how to sorting on a formula field? @4444

Comment: You just insert a Group using the Formula Field as the "Sorted and Grouped by" dropdown menu. If your new formula doesn't show up, then the shared variable isn't compatible. But it might work.

Comment: I got it! I create a summary of sum({@netCost}) and then sort by this is working! Thanks @4444

Comment: Sweet, I'll compile this into an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared variables open up a lot of room for error, but it should still be possible to sort by their results: Create a new formula field, and in its formula just put the shared `netCost` variable. From here you can insert a Group based on this new Formula field. Depending on the timing of events in the report, you might need to use `whileprintingrecords` in this Formula.

In this particular case you sorted on a Summary of your `netCost` value and sorting by that, which earned the correct answer.

Comment: Hi, another question, I try to add another table that make the record has duplicated. For example, I have a table for ticket, now I add a table is segment for details of ticket. If I use summary of netCost to sort is not correct, I need sort by running total to get the correct answer. Thanks @4444

Comment: @Iris I'm a bit unclear on what you mean - Maybe you should post a new question? (With some screenshots and in-depth descriptions)

Comment: I post a new question with some screenshots, hope this is more clear. Please go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722388/crystal-reports-how-to-sort-by-running-total, Thanks a lot, @4444.