# Sort on a Running Total

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to sort my report by `ticketCost`, but the regular summary of sum is got the total of all record include duplicate records.

[image: report design]

[image]

The left field is a Summary and the right field is a Running Total. Only the Summary shows up when I go to configure the group, it only allows me to pick the Summary.

How can I sort on a Running Total? Or is there some other way to use a Summary to avoid duplicated records?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal reports have two stages: the Reading stage and the Printing stage. Your Running Total fields are evaluated during Printing, but Grouping occurs during Reading. This is why you can't group on a Running Total - it won't be ready by the time Grouping needs it to be.

---

The best way around this is to perform the calculations is to write a custom SQL statement in the Database Expert.

[image]

This will return a new table in which you can calculate `ticketCost` as a field even before it reaches the report. Then group based on the new `ticketCost` field.